# How to finalise one-time payment summary with Firebase Extension "Run Payments with Stripe" on a ReactJs website

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I'm currently using Firebase for my ReactJs website.

I wanted to use stripe to add a payment module. So I created an account on Stripe and added the extension "Run Payments with Stripe" on my Firebase project.

Everything works fine on this extension on my website:

- I can make payment
- I'm well redirected to the Stripe payment interface
- The webhook add the payment document on my customer document on Firestore

But, I have one problem remaining : how to know which firestore document payment was concerned by the one-time payment a customer make on the current checkout session?

Firestore does not update checkout session document with the payment id, or the payment document with the checkout session id.

I tried to update manually the webhook function on Google Cloud but I don't think that's a good idea (and I don't know why but the update was not considered).

I don't want to list all payment the customer made and displayed it : I want to have this specific payment and display a summary of this order.

Does someone has clues on this?

Comment: Same problem here. A workaround could be to store a unique ID in field "metadata" of a Checkout Session document. Field "metadata" with all values will be available in the corresponding Payment document as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it appears that the function in the webhook handler [does not](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/ac1c33d4cba9b25b0fa9acb090ea5f7e38308e2d/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L600-L637) add Checkout Session data with the associated Firestore payment document.

I'd recommend creating an issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues) with your feedback/request. Alternatively you can configure a 2nd webhook to update the Firestore documents as you need.